# M5A99X Evo R2.0 wont post after new ram upgrade

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, post, led

Setup:

- ASUS M5A99X EVO R2.0 AM3+, AMD 990X, SATA 6Gb/s, USB 3.0, ATX, AMD Motherboard
- AMD FX-8350 Vishera 4.0GHz (4.2GHz Turbo) Socket AM3+ 125W Eight-Core Desktop Processor FD8350FRHKBOX
- 6 to 8GB of Corsair 1600MHz CMP4GX3M2A1600C9
- 650W Ultra ATX Power Supply (ULT-LSP650P)
- 240 GB Mushkin SSD (OS), 1 TB Samsung HD103UJ, 1.5 TB WD15EARS, 3 TB Seagate ST3000DM001
- SAPPHIRE Radeon HD 6850 1GB 256-bit GDDR5 PCI Express 2.1 x16 HDCP Ready
- Windows 8 64bit

Issue:

I installed 2x8 GB of G.Skill Sniper F3-1866C10D-16GSR, then booted up the computer. It made it past bios and immediately shut down. Every boot since then has been an immediate on-then-off. I have done the following:

- Reset CMOS (battery and 1-2/2-3 pin reset)
- Revert to old RAM.
- Use one stick of RAM (old and new)
- Flash back BIOS update to the latest
- Remove extra HDDs and graphics card
- Disconnect all hard drives and graphics card
- Replace PSU
- Reseat graphics card, RAM, CPU
- DirectKey and MemOk
- Swap CPU

In some of the cases, the computer will start then stop (fans and LEDs start then turn off immediately). Without the GPU, I can get the system to start, but CPU_LED light is solid red, all fans are running at maximum RPM, and there is no output to the video card (I had to use a Radeon X1550 to reach this point).

I am out of ideas at this point. Is it possible I fried something?

Edit: tested with alternative CPU, same behavior.

Cases (unfortunately, there is no native video for the motherboard):

- CPU / NO RAM / NO GFX : Boots, CPU_LED red
- CPU / RAM / NO GFX: Boots, CPU_LED red
- CPU / RAM / X1550 : Boots, CPU_LED red, no video output
- CPU / RAM / 5770 : On-then-off
- CPU / RAM / 6850 : On-then-off

RAM in these cases is either old or new, the behavior appeared the same.

Edit #2:

It seems like the 650W PSU has died, but with a replacement, I am still getting boot issues. I am RMA'ing the motherboard.

Edit #3:

GPU tested on another system and failed. Is it possible that the RAM addition fried my entire computer?

Edit #4: RMA'd the RAM as defective and was approved for a refund.

Comment: Failing PSUs often damage other components. If you have confirmed that yours is dead, then everything else may be damaged too. Sad but true. (Btw, are you making regular backups? If not then you should start, even if your HDDs survived this time you may not be that lucky next time. And don't consider RAID a backup, it won't help in such cases.)

Comment: @gronostaj I think there may still be some hope for the other components, as I was able to partially boot with a 750W Corsair PSU (what I used for the different cases). Replacement M5A99x on the way.

Comment: Followup - received the RMA board, added a new GTX 760, used the old corsair ram, old 8350, new 750W Corsair PSU, no post, same CPU LED Red. I will be testing an alternative CPU tomorrow, hopefully narrow it down to the CPU. Tried breadbox and stock cooler- both unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very localized case. I RMA'd the RAM, motherboard, and CPU (all the other parts have outlived their warranty). With the new CPU and motherboard I was able to post successfully.